# Object expected on jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a function that changes the source of an image tag to a background-image. This function should be really helpful for the way images will look in IE. I have tried debugging, but I get stuck on an object expected error. This happens on the second line:

```
if ( ! Modernizr.objectfit ) {
        $('.wrapper__figure').each(function () {
            var $container = $(this),
                    imgUrl = $container.find('img').attr('src');
            if (imgUrl) {
                $container
                    .css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');
            }  
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can get that code to cause that error in IE is if jQuery's `noConflict` has been used, so `$` isn't `jQuery` anymore (example: http://output.jsbin.com/bixijotala). If so, you probably want to use an IIFE to use a local `$`, passing in `jQuery`:

```
(function($) {
    if ( ! Modernizr.objectfit ) {
        $('.wrapper__figure').each(function () {
            var $container = $(this),
                    imgUrl = $container.find('img').attr('src');
            if (imgUrl) {
                $container
                    .css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');
            }  
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Or of course, you'd get this if you don't have jQuery loaded at all, in which case the answer is: Load jQuery, prior to running that code.